# Android progress bar gets exception

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

I'm working with web view in Android and I try to add progress bar, here are my codes :

```
case R.id.studentsite:
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            setContentView(R.layout.webview);
            WebView wv1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
            WebSettings ws1 = wv1.getSettings();
            final Activity activity = this;
            wv1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
              public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
              }
            });
            wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
              public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            });
            wv1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            ws1.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            wv1.loadUrl("http://www.studentsite.gunadarma.ac.id");
            break;
```

The problem is I got an exception on LOGCAT like this :

`09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.ugsimplify.ugweb.callintent(ugweb.java:89)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.ugsimplify.ugweb$1.onClick(ugweb.java:29)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-17 13:51:34.487: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1331):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: activity.setProgress is this correct??

Comment: It should be correct but it doesn't show any progress bar, would you like to help?

Comment: you might get answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4988676/1012284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call below line in `Oncreate` just after `super.oncreate`

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

You are calling it in Button click, for which you would have already set a content. 
Progress bar feature can only be requested before setContentView for the very first time.

Comment: thank you for solving my problem, but can you tell me why I haven't see anything about progress bar, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: it will be at the title bar. Activity progress bar takes values from 0 to 10000, So i guess you will have to multiply by 100 rather than 1000.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hi Here is problem that you have call.


  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS); before  setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    It should be call below the setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    Answer :-


                setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the logcat you've used the requestFeature after setting the contentView.

The part of the code you've posted is perfect.

I suspect you've already used setContentView somewhere else, maybe in onCreate method.